# Using string and functions together within php class properties

Tags: php, wordpress

in my theme `functions.php` i created a class contains some properties. my problem this when i use both string and functions in my property class show me the error say `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'`

for example i want when i print this property in my class show me the post title within `<h1><a href=""></a></h1>` but when i use the `the_title()` wordpress function within html tag string show me the above error. how i can use the `the_title()` function until show me the title correctly?

```
class YPE_post_formats {
    public $VP_icon = '<h1><a href="">'.the_title().'</a></h1>';
}
```

Comment: You can't do that in a class public variable.

Comment: You can't define a property value using anything that requires evaluation at runtime, such as calling a function like `the_title()`..... quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`

Comment: but tell me how i can do this in my class? i want resolve this class to me

Comment: `class YPE_post_formats {
    public $VP_icon;
    public function __construct()
        $this->VP_icon = '<h1><a href="">'.the_title().'</a></h1>';
    }
}`

Comment: The Wordpress function `the_title()` will echo the title on screen. You can use `get_the_title()` instead to save the title to a variable.

Comment: @Mark Baker thank you it is work perfectly

Comment: @Kirk Beard  yes it is must be used `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()` thank you for your note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use functions in class property definition. Instead you could do it as follows:

```
class YPE_post_formats {
    public $VP_icon;

    public function __construct($the_title)
    {
        $this->VP_icon = '<h1><a href="">'.$the_title.'</a></h1>';
    }
}

$obj = new YPE_post_formats(get_the_title());

// To echo $VP_icon
echo $obj->$VP_icon;
```

#### Edit

I edited my answer removing the definition of `the_title()` as it is already defined in WordPress. Furthermore, I changed `the_title()` to `get_the_title()` as this will not echo but get the contents of the title.

Comment: thank you for help but in my case i don't need `the_title` function because in wordpress the `the_title()` is defined over all theme files

Comment: thank you it is better to use `get_the_title()` directly and not assign it to the `$the_title` variable

Comment: @SAFEEN1990 I'm not sure if that function is available in your class. But indeed that's possible.